# How do you check if a basis of matrices are orthogonal, in a given inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, orthogonality

The only thing I know is to use gram-schmidt and see if I get back the same matrices. But I thought perhaps that's not the method you should use if all you want to do is check for orthogonality, and maybe there is a smarter way?

I am a beginner, so Gram-Schmidt is about as advanced as things go for me.
Would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: What about the straight way, computing all inner products ? In other words, $MM^T$ must be diagonal.

Comment: @Yves Daoust If I have a basis for 3x3 matrices for instance, wouldnt I have nine vectors to check? And I would have to take the inner product of every vector with each other vector, so that would take a long time. Thought perhaps there was something faster that I hadn't thought of :) Also I don't understand the product with the transpose you mention (sorry I don't know how to write that). Why does that need to be diagonal?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, what do you mean by $M$? If  $M$ is the matrix whose columns are $\text{vec}(B_i)$, where the $B_i$ are basis matrices, $\text{vec}$ is the vectorization operator that converts a matrix into a column vector and $i=1,\ldots,n^2$ for $n\times n$ matrices, I can see that $MM^T$ must be a diagonal matrix if the basis is orthogonal, but this is  far from obvious to a beginner.

Comment: What do you mean by a basis of *matrices*? What is your vector space, and how is the inner product defined?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I've just pointed out that this is not obvious at all to a beginner, who can think that $M$ is an element of the basis and ask "Why does that need to be diagonal?".

Comment: @YvesDaoust, are you asking me or @kritters? The question is not mine, I'm just trying to help. Let me try one more time. The question is about a vector space of $n\times n$ matrices, an $n^2$-dimensional vector space. When you say that $MM^T$ must be diagonal, without further specification, one could not see as obvious that you are making reference to a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix whose columns are the vectorized basis matrices.

Comment: @kritters, are you computing the inner products by hand? If you are, you should not! This type of computation can be made almost instantaneously with few lines of code in Octave  or any alternative like Python with the Numpy library.

Comment: @jobe Thank you for your response! we aren't allowed to use computers during exams unfortunately, but that's good to know so I can use it for assignments at least :) My situation is not a specific inner product or a specific field, sometimes they are complex and sometimes the inner product is not the standard inner product. We have a lot of these assignments to hand in, and the ones with the matrices are taking a particularly long time. Do you know for which inner products this MM^t works (and what about complex numbers), and perhaps a place where I can learn about it?

Comment: It works for the standard inner product between two matrices $A$ and $B$: $\langle A, B\rangle=\text{trace}(A^\dagger B)$, where the dagger symbol $\dagger$ stands for complex conjugate transpose. I don't know if that is the case for another inner product. Anyway, there is no computational advantage writing the $n^2\times n^2$ matrix $M$ and compute $M^\dagger M$ compared to just take all inner products. In fact, $(M^\dagger M)_{ij}=\text{trace}(B_i^\dagger B_j)$, where the $B_i$ are basis matrices.

Comment: @jobe Thank you, that is very helpful! I was a little confused by the other comments and couldn't find help in my textbook, but now I get it. very good explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better way than computing all $\frac{(n-1)n}2$ inner products, as they are independent of each other.

So in principle $O(n^3)$ operations. If $n$ is large enough ($n>100$), a fast matrix product algorithm such as Strassen can be thought of. This will lower to $O(n^{\log_27})$ operations.

Gram-Schmidt is a viable alternative, as the complexity is also $O(n^3)$ [$n^3$ additions and multiplications; also $n^2$ divisions]; be sure to use the *modified* Gram-Schmidt version, for better numerical stability.

Comment: Gram Schmidt works by projecting new vectors onto the already orthogonals and subtract that projection. 
Part of the projection process is an inner product. So it's easy to see, that Gram Schmidt is at least as expensive as calculating the upper triangular of $MM^T$ (if $M$ is your presumed basis).